# String.format( ) format arguments

Tags: java

I saw some code with something like

```
String.format("%3d\t%s" , stuff, stuff).
```

What does the stuff in the quotation marks mean? I know \t is just a tab, but I do not know what the %'s and other things are.

Also, are there any more of those types of symbols that can be used for formatting Strings?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: The documentation is actually to be found on the `java.util.Formatter` class API, not printf.

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) is the link for the formatter docs.

Answer (score 1):

String.format takes a [printf format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).  Java's format is documented in the JDK documentation for [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

The format string you are using breaks down as follows:

- %3d format (convert) the first argument into a 3 digit integer
- \t a tab character
- %s format (convert) the next (second) argumet as a string

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Java but in c c++ means an 3 spaces integer first(%3d) and a string (%s), the values after commas are the variables that take their positions. Maybe a variant of printf method

Comment: You're right in spirit, but adding a link to the `Formatter` API would help in a big way.

Comment: I know. But I'm on my phone. I have no many options but your right 100%